# Pytest-coverage combine does not calculates same coverage as the whole test suite

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov, pytest-split

I have a long Python unit test suite that I can run with the following command:

```
pytest --cov=. tests/unit/
```

It reports a coverage of 77%. However if I execute the test suite in chunks using [pytest-split](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-split/) and then combine the results it gets lower coverage, I am wondering how this behaviour happens? I would expect that both approaches should calculate the same coverage, is my expectation right?

For the sake of the details, here are the commands I use to combine the results:

```
COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage_1 pytest --cov=. tests/unit/ --splits 2 --group 1
COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage_2 pytest --cov=. tests/unit/ --splits 2 --group 2
coverage combine --keep .coverage_*
coverage report
```

By the way this is the .coveragerc configuration file:

```
[run]
omit = tests/*
parallel = True
relative_files = True
```

Any hint or help is going to be much appreciated.

Comment: The reason is described here: https://jerry-git.github.io/pytest-split/#interactions-with-other-pytest-plugins: "duration_based_chunks algorithm is incompatible with test-order-randomization plugins"